# Why is my CSS stylesheet not working using NodeJS and Express?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, ejs

I am using EJS and Express for an application I am doing just for fun.
In my application, I am utilizing partials from a folder called views/partials. My css stylesheet is located in a directory called public. I have included `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` in my express routes directory. And it is working on all other pages besides this one, (edit.ejs):

```
<%- include('partials/head') %>


<div id="updatecustomer">
    <h1>Update Customer Profile</h1>

    <form method="post" action="/<%=customer.id%>?_method=PATCH">
        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstname" placeholder="<%= customer.firstName %>">
        <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastname" placeholder="<%= customer.lastName %>">
        <label for="phonenumber">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="contactNumber" id="phonenumber" placeholder="<%= customer.contactNumber %>">
        <label for="address">Address</label>
        <input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="<%= customer.address %>">
        <label for="city">City</label>
        <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="<%= customer.city %>">
        <label for="state">State</label>
        <input type="text" name="state" id="state" placeholder="<%= customer.state %>">
        <label for="zipcode">Zipcode</label>
        <input type="text" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" placeholder="<%= customer.zipcode %>">
        <button type="submit">Update Customer</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

A snippet from index.js of my get/patch request, (I'm not using a database, simply an array of objects.):

```
app.get('/:id/edit', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const customer = customers.find(c => c.id === id)
    res.render('edit', { customer })
})

app.patch('/:id', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const foundCustomer = customers.find(c => c.id === id);

    const customerFirstname = req.body.firstName;
    foundCustomer.firstName = customerFirstname;

    const customerLastname = req.body.lastName;
    foundCustomer.lastName = customerLastname;

    const customerAddress = req.body.address;
    foundCustomer.address = customerAddress;

    const customerCity = req.body.city;
    foundCustomer.city = customerCity;

    const customerState = req.body.state;
    foundCustomer.state = customerState;

    const customerZip = req.body.zipcode;
    foundCustomer.zip = customerZip;

    const customerContactNum = req.body.contactNumber;
    foundCustomer.contactNumber= customerContactNum;

    res.redirect('/');
})
```

I have tried adding the styles manually to the page, clearing my browser data, and spent hours looking up a solution and remained stumped on this issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Is `app.patch` being invoked?  Your form is doing a post, so I'd think you'd need to use `app.post`, not `app.patch`.

Comment: I have no idea what any of the form code you're showing us has to do with your CSS style sheets.  As with all static resources you're attempting to use `express.static()` with, we need to see these things in order to help: **1)** The exact `express.static()` line of code you're using.  **2)** Where in your server file system the desired CSS style sheet is.  **3)** The exact HTML tag you're trying to use to load the CSS stylesheet in your web page.  When you supply those three things, we can tell you which of those needs to be fixed.